# How can i retrieve the title field from the below mentioned json :

Tags: java, json

[image]How can I retrieve the title field from the below mentioned JSON :

```
{"feed":[{"image":"http:\/\/xyz\/xyz\/600x519\/web2images\/www.xyz.com\/2015\/09\/16\/xyz.jpg","story_id":"83","slug_intro":"xyz","title":"xyz","videoflag":0,"version":"2","channel_slno":"123","pubdate":"2015-09-17 00:08:00"}],"bigimage":0}
```

Please provide the code in JAVA.

Please suggest why i am getting this error as shown in above figure

Comment: pick your favorite or one of the many json parsers. and make it so!

Comment: Please indent your json code.

Comment: which JSON class are you using, I mean how are you parsing the JSON string as Java Object, any code sample?

Comment: Object obj=JSONValue.parse(result); System.out.println(obj); where obj is above mentioned decoded json and result is encoded json

Answer (score 2):

```
String myJSONString = "{\"feed\":[{\"image\":\"http://xyz/xyz/600x519/web2images/www.xyz.com/2015/09/16/xyz.jpg\",\"story_id\":\"83\",\"slug_intro\":\"xyz\",\"title\":\"xyz\",\"videoflag\":0,\"version\":\"2\",\"channel_slno\":\"123\",\"pubdate\":\"2015-09-17 00:08:00\"}],\"bigimage\":0}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myJSONString);
JSONArray dataJsonArray = json.getJSONArray("feed");

for(int i=0; i<dataJsonArray.length; i++) {
 JSONObject dataObj = dataJsonArray.get(i);
 String title = dataObj.getString("title");
 //Similarly you can extract for other fields.
}
```

Output : `Title:xyz`

Comment: Hi... I have used this code to get the above mentioned json...Object obj=JSONValue.parse(result);
System.out.println(obj);  can you please proceed from here.... It would be really thanks full

Comment: Have you faced any issue to used this code?

Comment: Hi please find the attached screen shot above

Comment: You have to use type casting, for example String myJSONString = (String)obj;

Comment: That i have done showing error on these line   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myJSONString);
   JSONArray dataJsonArray = json.getJSONArray("feed");

   for(int i=0; i<dataJsonArray.length; i++)
   {
    JSONObject dataObj = dataJsonArray.get(i);
    String title = dataObj.getString("title");
   }

Comment: But I have not seen in your screen shot image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93959/discussion-between-sourabh-shukla-and-shiladittya-chakraborty).